# operator (plus add) in entity framework core send an error

Tags: asp.net-core, sequence, entity-framework-core

When using sql select I need a counter for my sequence row like this:

```
 var result = from d in data
                     select new[]
                     {
                Convert.ToString((count++))
            };
```

but this syntax gives the following error message:

```
An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator   Vehicle.app..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
```

Comment: Please use proper capitalization, punctuation, grammar, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using LINQ (e.g. `from x in data select { ... }`) the expression in the selection is translated into a SQL statement and executed in the database. How would an assignment like `count++` work in a database? I think you're better off with selecting the records from the database and apply the sequence number on the *in memory* list of data rather than on the *queryable* collection which represents the database. For example:

```
var data = (from d in data select new { ... }).ToList();
var result = data.Select(new { id = Convert.ToString(count++), ... }).ToList();
```

Comment: but i using AsEnumerable it's more lighter than using list

Comment: @Chris do you mean the first or second line?

Comment: i use something like this  var result = data.AsEnumerable().Select(d => new[]{ (count++).ToString() });

Comment: @Chris as long as you make sure you call `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to execute the query on the database before you call the second `Select` statement.